# Did NASA director Charles Bolden claim that an alien invasion will happen soon?

Tags: united-states, space-flight, nasa, aliens

Russian news site "Federal News Agency" (FAN) [today published "Директор NASA заявил, что до вторжения инопланетян осталось несколько месяцев"](https://riafan.ru/734478-direktor-nasa-zayavil-chto-do-vtorzheniya-inoplanetyan-ostalos-neskolko-mesyacev?utm_source=smi2):

> Директора NASA Чарльза Болдена отправили в отпуск по болезни, после того, как он публично заявил, что вторжение внеземных пришельцев произойдет в ближайшее время.
>
> ... «Нас могу захватить в любой момент!» — заявил он, выступая на конференции NASA. После чего его тут же увели со сцены два сотрудника космического агентства.

(translation mine)

> NASA Director Charles Bolden was sent on sick leave, after he publicly announced that the invasion of extraterrestrial aliens would happen in the near future.
>  
> ... "We can be invaded at any time!" - he said, speaking at a NASA conference. Then he was immediately led off the stage by two employees of the space agency.

I found an English site with similar claim (though awkward English makes me think it was a bad translation from Russian in the first place): [The director of NASA has publicly declared invasion of aliens](https://steemit.com/history/@shamanred/the-director-of-nasa-has-publicly-declared-invasion-of-aliens).

> Charles Bolden heading the American aerospace agency NASA on April 22 this year at a conference in Houston has declared that aliens can intrude (to begin war with people of Earth) on our planet in several months.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

No. The original source of this claim is a satirical news site.

This claim is from an [article in World News Daily Report](http://worldnewsdailyreport.com/nasa-administrator-suspended-after-claims-of-imminent-alien-invasion/), which carries the following disclaimer in the footer:

> World News Daily Report assumes all responsibility for the satirical nature of its articles and for the fictional nature of their content. All characters appearing in the articles in this website – even those based on real people – are entirely fictional and any resemblance between them and any person, living, dead or undead, is purely a miracle.

Comment: Additionally it should be noted that Bolden resigned as NASA Administrator on January 20, 2017.

Answer (score 24):

The [current answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/38100/23404) correctly addresses the truthiness of the claim; but neglects to mention that the satirical article in question from WNDR was actually NOT made up from scratch, but instead cued from an actual news of Bolden's statements in [2015 that discussed aliens and Area 51](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2016/03/12/area-51-and-extra-terrestrial-life-both-exist-says-head-of-nasa/) (albeit, far less content in his statement, as far as exciting news).

He DID discuss aliens and possibility/likelyhood of future contact, or at least finding evidence of aliens (but not any "invasions", nor specific timelines):

> “Today we know that there are literally thousands, if not millions of other planets, many of which may be very similar to our own earth. So some of us, many of us believe that we're going to find...evidence that there is life elsewhere in the universe."

He also discussed Area 51 as real, except without Will Smith or alien ships:

> “There is an Area 51,” he said. “It’s not what many people think. I’ve been to a place called that but it’s a normal research and development place. I never saw any aliens or alien spacecraft or anything when I was there.

*(on a curious note: he very interestingly did NOT say "there **are no** aliens/spacecraft" there, just "I never saw"... There's clearly grounds for a conspiracy in that wording).*

Comment: I don't see any relationship between those 2015 statements and the claim in the question. The only thing they have in common is that both involve extraterrestrial life (which is a topic that, as head of NASA, he's been asked about and answered questions about on multiple occasions - e.g. [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/15/we-are-not-alone-in-universe-nasa-habitable-planets_n_5588455.html), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwwu3pZNv5s).)

Comment: I also see a world of difference between "extraterrestrial life" and "aliens" (as in sentient, possibly spacefaring creatures). *Lichen* would be extraterrestrial life...